# How to generate sequence in MySQL 5.1community edition

Tags: mysql

Can somebody please show me how generate a sequence in MySQL 5.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table users
(
user_id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
username varbinary(32) unique not null
...
)
engine=innodb;
```

you could also do

```
drop table if exists users_seq;
create table users_seq
(
next_val int unsigned not null default 0
)
engine = innodb;

insert into users_seq values (0);

drop table if exists users;
create table users
(
user_id int unsigned not null primary key,
username varbinary(32) unique not null
)
engine=innodb;

delimiter #
create trigger users_before_ins_trig before insert on users
for each row
begin
declare v_id int unsigned default 0;
    select next_val+1 into v_id from users_seq;
    set new.user_id = v_id;
  update users_seq set next_val = v_id;
end#

delimiter ;

insert into users (username) values ('f00'),('foo'),('bar');

select * from users;
select next_val from users_seq;
```

Comment: does this sql will create any separate sequence object in db? Bcoz my app like to access the sequence object and get the next value. Also I want to keep the same logic for diff db ie. mysql,oracle,sqlserver etc. So if possible I like to give a name to sequence same like Oracle, so that later on I can access that object.

Comment: If you want such a behaviour, you should consider using an ORM.

Comment: i will try this solution, looks like this will solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't have sequences, however it does have the auto-increment feature.

http://www.experts123.com/q/does-mysql-5.1-have-sequences.html

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  customer_id bigint(21) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT 
);
```